# Can't get return value/Modify referenced variable from generic method

Tags: c#, generics, methods, return-value

Apologies for this dummy question. The problem is totally unrelated to generic or C#, only...my IQ.

WHAT JUST HAPPENED:

My data container is a static member variable, in the getter function it should be:

```
get
{
    if (_Data == null)
    {
        _Data = new DataStore();
        return _Data;
    }
    return _Data;
}
```

I wrote:

```
get
{
    if (_Data == null)
    {
        return new DataStore();
    }
    return _Data;
}
```

So every time getting the `Data.XXXDataSet` from outside, it always returns a `new Data()`, so null for every `XXXDataSet` in it.

Thanks for your kindly help and... should I delete this question now?

=======original question======

Description of the problem:

I want to write a generic method to load some database entries to memory (for editor), the process is something like this:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    var list = new List<MyDataEntity>((from d in db.MyDataEntity select d).Count());

    foreach (var c in (from d in db.MyDataEntity select d).AsNoTracking())
        list.Add(c);

    Data.MyDataStore = new ObservableCollection<MyDataEntity>(list);
}
```

This works just fine, the corresponding generic method I wrote is:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> LoadDBEntries<T>() where T : class
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        var dbSet = db.Set<T>();
        var list = new List<T>((from d in dbSet select d).Count());

        foreach (var c in (from d in dbSet select d).AsNoTracking())
            list.Add(c);

        return new ObservableCollection<T>(list);
    }
}
```

This method runs correctly(as it seems), the list will be filled with db data(so is the observable collection), but as I wrote:

```
Data.MyDataStore = DBWorker.LoadDBEntries<MyDataEntity>();
```

`Data.MyDataStore` remains null (original state) after execution.

I tried to do it this way:

```
// I know the ref for coll is unnecessary but...
public static void LoadDBEntries<T>(ref ObservableCollection<T> coll) where T : class
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        var dbSet = db.Set<T>();

        var list = new List<T>((from d in dbSet select d).Count());

        foreach (var c in (from d in dbSet select d).AsNoTracking())
            list.Add(c);

        coll = new ObservableCollection<T>(list);
    }
}
```

And ran it with:

```
DBWorker.LoadDBEntries(ref Data.MyDataStore);
```

results the same (`Data.MyDataStore` is null), but from debugger it tells that data is correctly loaded to 'coll'(in the way I understand it, this is the `Data.MyDataStore` variable, no?). But after this method runs out of scope, the `Data.MyDataStore` remains null.

Can someone tell me why this happens? Did I misunderstood generic in C# (I'm totally a noob for this) or more fundamentally, C# itself?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an aside, `from d in db.MyDataEntity select d` is equivalent to `db.MyDataEntity`.

Comment: Are you sure the instance of `Data` you're seeing that has a null `MyDataStore` is the same instance you are setting?  Your method will definitely return a value, if you stick a breakpoint after it's set you should see it isn't null.

Comment: wow, thanks man, didn't realise this one.

Comment: I debugged and found that it returned valid value(with var result = DBWorker.LoadDBEntries<MyDataEntity>(), result is correct) so it seems not a generic problem. But I just found something weirder in my code -- even if I initialized Data.MyDataStore (definition: public ObservableCollection<MyDataEntity> MyDataStore) using Data.MyDataStore = new ObservableCollection<MyDataEntity>(), debugger still says IT IS NULL(why does it ever compile and run!). I will do some research for this then edit my question(the problem seems irrelevant to the title now). thanks very mush for the notice!